# Mass Uploading Configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, database, configurable-product

I am looking to figure out a solution for mass uploading configurable products on magento. I have been reading around and people have mentioned using magmi but I wanted to know if there is a simple solution out there. I have also been looking to see if there are any threads explaining this.

Here is an example:
[image]

In this picture you can see that every sku has the same configuration (conf 1, conf 2 and conf 3) but for each product those configuration values are different prices. Meaning all products have their own unique prices. I have been trying to find people on freelancer for help and asking around various websites but I am pretty desperate for a solution as I have over 250,000 skus that are configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Of Course, one of the best solution for mass uploading configurable products on Magento is MAGMI (Magento Mass Importer). Though MAGMI is not a module for Magento but works separately.  It uses direct SQ to manipulate data and comprises various nice re-indexing features.

MAGMI is completely free indeed!

Here are some important threads and documents which might help you to know more about this.

**Download Link**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

**Wiki Page**

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

**Installation and Configuring Tips**

http://www.phpro.be/news/magmi-magento-mass-importer

**Some Pros and Cons**

http://fabrizioballiano.net/2011/04/19/magmi-the-best-magento-importer/

**An article admiring the project**

http://benfrain.com/magmi-the-best-way-to-import-into-magento/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you happen to know about a sample .csv with all the required columns and headings for a magento configurable product database upload?